# Cannot create account - invalid email

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am having trouble using the new PayPal developer Beta center - I was previously using the classic API via the sandbox site. I have logged into the developer center with my username and password, however I cannot create any sandbox accounts, and I cannot import my existing sandbox accounts either.

In both cases, when entering an email address, I receive an error stating that the email address is invalid, even though it is a perfectly valid email address.

Has anyone else encountered problems creating accounts?

The API documentation states that the email address doesn't even need to be a real email address as no emails are sent outside of the test environment, yet even entering my real address is rejected as being an invalid email address! Do the addresses need to be in a particular format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your email address have a dash in it?  There were some issues with email addresses when they had a dash in the email?  If it does, try using a different email without a dash.  Also try clearing cookies and cache before attempting.  Also if you are using Internet Explorer, you might try using Firefox or Chrome.  There have been fewer issues with these browsers when using the new developer.paypal.com site.

Comment: yup - my email had a . in it. Removing that solves the issue. If you're going to add email verification to a site, at least make sure it works!

Comment: Glad to hear its working.  This has already been brought up with our engineering team.